# Can I disable "Online Accounts" and still use Empathy?

Tags: empathy, online-accounts

I want to have control over what happens with my online presence so I absolutely do not want any software to be able to log in to any of my online accounts and post/change/delete things. Ever. Nor do I know where the login credentials that Ubuntu Online Accounts uses is stored, i.e. who has access to that information? Allowing software to access my accounts automatically is bad, but potentially giving other people access to my accounts is even worse.

However, I do like to chat and was happy with Empathy storing passwords *locally* since it would only allow me to chat but didn't do anything else.

I want to fully disable Ubuntu Online Accounts on my machine while still using chat software. How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps you'd better chat through a browser, in which case, you never have to input any personal info into Ubuntu Online Accounts.

Comment: Online Accounts is merely a manager for all your programs. Empathy is just as likely as Online Accounts to give all your details to Canonical. Canonical doesn't do anything with your information (other than in the Dash). So you have NOTHING to worry about, if you really are that paranoid, use Firefox and DON'T save your passwords. But you don't REALLY know if Mozilla are stealing your information or not! So nothing is safe!

Comment: Where is the information stored? If that is local, I would be fine with it, but I can't find that anywhere.

Also, having the choice to use this (time saving) feature or not seems like a normal thing to me... I like Ubuntu, but if they're becoming the next Google / Facebook / Microsoft, it might be time to switch :(